# Is maxima able to solve such integral? If no, what can?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, maxima-software

I was sitting and decided to get a precise magnetic field equation from Bio-Savar law, and got out this handsome formula (by the way, is there a way to use ASCIIMath here on Mathematics?):
$$
\vec{B}(x,y,z)=\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi L}{d}}\frac{\begin{vmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ -R\sin t & R\cos t & \frac{d}{2\pi} \\ x-R\cos t & y-R\sin t & z-\frac{td}{2\pi} \end{vmatrix}}{\sqrt{(x-R\cos t)^2+(y-R\sin t)^2 +\left(z-\frac{td}{2\pi}\right)^2}^3}\,\, dt
$$
Maxima opened a determinant for me, but it didn't take an integral, maybe because this is quite complex thing to integrate. 
Is there a way I can take this integral using free computer algebra systems? If yes, what program should I try?

After some time:
Decided to use numerical methods, I will take the concrete solenoid lengths, radiuses, coil thicknesses and coordinates and read wiki for other methods of calculation of the flux density in real solenoids.

Comment: The formula is quite unreadable (maybe because I am seeing this ASCIIMath for the first time). You may want to type it here.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read the link well enough to confidently type it into *Mathematica*, although that could possibly be pure ignorance on my part. We use standard LaTeX format for typeset here, in particular a subset of [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Usually if you try to typeset your equation as best you can, someone will be kind enough to fix it for you assuming they know exactly what you meant.

Comment: What do you mean by unreadable? I can make an image then, one minute

Comment: oh, somebody has already added formula. Thanks, the kind man!)

Comment: After thought, I am partially going to run with tail between legs here, but if I **had** to do this (or take a bullet to the knee), what I would do is break that resulting vector (take the determinant) in the numerator into its $\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$ components, then attempt to take 3 integrals, each component divided by the denominator and cross the fingers. Note that for "free", I can usually coerce [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) into computing any integral I can do in *Mathematica*, but I usually set up in *Mathematica* asI know the syntax. WA has access to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Good advise, thanks, but I think it doesn't matter too much how to group the polynomial in numerator. Of course this integral should be taken as a sum of integrals, the case is that this one is really quite complex and should be calculated using computer algebra system, so that I'm sure I don't make a stupid mistake somewhere. If I can't calculate it symbolically, then I would try with concrete numbers.

Comment: J.W. takes a bullet to the knee. Ouch. Indeed complicated. I just took the $\vec{i}$ component, and after a few minutes *Mathematica* just regurgitated the integral back at me. This means it cannot even recognize it as being a constituent of elliptics, gamma, obscure distributions, and the like. I am pretty sure I typed it in correctly. Best of luck. If you wind up resorting to numerical methods, be sure to fire that out in the post. ;)

Comment: The same with maxima. So then I see why there is no such formula on wiki. It should be calculated only with numbers then.
I'm sure I would use numerical methods, it seems there is no other way.

Comment: @user1956641 I can't remember for certain, but I'm pretty sure I did this integral a few years back when I was working through Jackson. Mathematica and I had many fights over integrals like these where it told me it didn't think it could solve them, but the lazy bastard actually could. The trick is to scale down the integrals to something less computationally intensive.